# Subdomains cant load css or images

Tags: css, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

First time happend this to me , i created a subdomain example.domain.com and a link to style.css cant be loaded. All files are there when i try to open file with URL it show me 404 not found.

But on domain.com/example it work and css and images ?

I searched alot on internet but i didnt find noting to resolve my problem.I tryed with htacess

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} admin.example.com
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [css|images|js]/(.*)\.(.*)
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```

and still didnt resolve my problem any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use parentheses instead of braces to use "or" comparisons on sequences in regex. Your top condition should also be a regular expression.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:css|images|js)/(.*)\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: I dont work , i need from some example.com/folder to folder.example.com to get css and images. When i open full url to css or image it show me 404 not found but its on server php files are ok on both links but images or css is not good on subdomain on folder are ok?

Comment: Yes u can see online here http://zdr.xredirect.info/ or http://www.xredirect.info/zdr/ just php file and css

Comment: What's the full link being accessed? It should be something like `http://admin.example.com/css/file.css`.

Comment: i just gived example code , i edited that  http://zdr.xredirect.info/css/style.css         www.xredirect.info/zdr/css/style.css

Comment: Yea, I realized that the domain was different. Which folder are you putting this file in?

Comment: i first created subdomain zdr , after when she was created in ftp i put all files there in 'zdr' folder on one link show all good but when i try this other dont work php files are good just css and img

Comment: My bad, I should have been more specific. Which folder are you putting the .htaccess file in?

Comment: in zdr folder  htacess file :                                                                                        `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zdr\.xredirect\.info$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:css|images|js)/(.*)\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.xredirect.info%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: And did you use `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: I forgott but i set now and didnt change anything

Comment: If you used the code snippet in my answer and that is the only thing in your htaccess file, it should work fine.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zdr\.xredirect\.info$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:css|images|js)/(.*)\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.xredirect.info%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]`                                                                                                    i have this only in my htacess file

Comment: Either something else on your server is blocking it or your server is configured improperly. I tested the code you just showed and it worked fine for me.

Comment: No problem. Good luck figuring it out.